# Ajax response not working as expected from PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling the JS function `cancelAppointment` on button click, I can confirm that the function is running okay as the first alert is shown.

I have followed many guides to try and get this to work but they are yielding no results.

At the moment the success message is not being showed and the row is not being deleted. I can confirm the PHP script works fine.

the function is as below:

```
<head>
<script>
    //Making the call to ajax this is encased in a function so it is not called pre-maturely
    function deleteAppointment()
    {
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        alert("Trying to run!");

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "http://www.website.com/delete_appointment.php",
                //data : "",                
                success : function(response) {
                    //Success
                    alert("Deleted");
                }
            }); 
        });
    }
</script>
```

For the moment, until I get the ajax to work the PHP contains PDO, that will delete from both the `Appointments` & `AppointmentLines` table with an ID of 1000. I will parse this in once this first part works.

Comment: Add to your ajax a `complete` callback (same way as `success`), output `response` to console (`console.dir(response)`)and see what you've got there.

Comment: It returned an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` inside a method makes no sense. Learn about document ready and what that is used for. Second, do you have jQuery included in your page?

Comment: It is wordpress so yes it is auto included using jQuery in place of $

Comment: Your script doesn't know that `$` is jQuery. Replace `$.ajax` with `jQuery.ajax`. Also remove `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` and closing `});` and move your script to the bottom of your html before `</body>` tag

Comment: That is correct, if you submit an answer with that I will mark correct. Cheers.

Comment: Instead I passed `$` as a parameter (If that's what it would be called) to the DOM function so it did recognize it. :) but same concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Wordpress the jQuery library included in the noConflict() mode, so the global $ shortcut for jQuery is not available, [see more details here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

To make it work change `$` to jQuery:

```
function deleteAppointment()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "http://www.website.com/delete_appointment.php",
        success : function(response) {
            alert("Deleted");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what response the Ajax method is expecting to receive. 
Make the response either 'text' (as shown in the example bellow) or make the response 'json'. You just add 'dataType: "text"' as a setting to the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "http://www.website.com/delete_appointment.php",
            dataType : "text",                
            success : function(response) {
                //Success
                alert("Deleted");
            }
        });
```

Currently you're your success method is waiting for the value of "response" to be returned however you are not defining what it is.

EDIT: I was corrected that it should be dataType not data for the setting I was originally talking about.

Comment: Is it required to return text?

Comment: That did not make the row get deleted.

Comment: `data` is not required. Also you are giving a wrong format for that - it should be json key-value format like `{ key1: value1, key2: value2}` for POST requests

Comment: Try it out, I think that may be the issue at hand. Another issue you may be facing however is that you are not actually sending any data to the server in this instance. 

Another possible issue you may be having is that you're "delete_appointment.php" script may only be running on a "get" request, considering you are not sending any data to the server.

Comment: Nikolay Ermakov, you are correct, I was meaning the "dataType" setting.

Comment: Thanks guys found the issue :)

Comment: What did the issue end up being so I can document it for future readers?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,

Because I was using wordpress you must use `jQuery` in place of `$` I needed to wrap this in a DOM function with `$` defined so that jQuery would understand `$`

I kept the `data` argument commented in the end.

This issue was caused due to wordpress requiring slightly different syntax when calling a jQuery function. Thanks for your help everyone.